# Shading area between curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading, intersections

I am an old LaTeX user but just beginning to discover PGF and TikZ. I am trying to shade areas between 3 curves and from what I read I could do it with min and max functions, but forwhatever reasons my equations aren't liked by the compiler. So I tried using shadeareabetween function `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` but that also wasn't liked by [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) or Mac compiler. So I had to subtract one curve from another manually but then I have to paint the lower area white and that spoils my axis ticks. Can you guys help me with this. Maybe show me a few tricks that can help this code a lot shorter. I am basically plotting 3 inflation rates from 8c at 2014.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{ wasysym }
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.25,label/.style={%
   postaction={ decorate,transform shape,
   decoration={ markings, mark=at position .39 with \node #1;}}}]

    \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
      legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
        %height=9cm,
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=\$/kWh,
       xmin=2004,   xmax=2050,
    ymin=5,   ymax=35,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        %width=9cm,
        xtick={2005,  2010, 2013, 2020, 2030, 2040,2050},
        xticklabels={05,10,13,2020,2030,2040,2050},
    ytick={6,8,10,15,...,30},
    ]

    %\addplot {8*1.08^x};
    %\addlegendentry{8\%}

    \addplot[   color=black,
                solid,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid},
                smooth] coordinates {
        (2005,6)
        (2006,7.32)
        (2007,9.42)
        (2008,10.29)
        (2009,8.09)
        (2010,6.73)
        (2011,9.60)
        (2012,9.62)
        (2013,8.66)
        (2014,8)

    };
    \addlegendentry{Retail}




\addplot+[mark=none,draw=none,fill=orange!70,domain=2014:2050] {8*1.07^(x-2014)}\closedcycle;

\addplot+[mark=none,draw=none,fill=white,domain=2014:2050] {8*1.03^(x-2014)}\closedcycle;




\addplot[name path global=T,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.75:2050,label={[below]{3\%}}]{8.*(1.03)^( x -  2014 )};
    %\addlegendentry{3\% inflation}

    \addplot[label={[below]{5\%}},name path global = F,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.85:2048,]{8.*(1.05)^( x -  2014 )};
    %\addlegendentry{5\% inflation}

    \addplot[label={[below]{7\%}},name path global=S,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.85:2050]{8.*(1.07)^( x -  2014 )};


\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the option `axis on top` for the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{ wasysym }
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.25,label/.style={%
   postaction={ decorate,transform shape,
   decoration={ markings, mark=at position .39 with \node #1;}}}]

    \begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=\textwidth,
      legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
        %height=9cm,
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=\$/kWh,
       xmin=2004,   xmax=2050,
    ymin=5,   ymax=35,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        %width=9cm,
        xtick={2005,  2010, 2013, 2020, 2030, 2040,2050},
        xticklabels={05,10,13,2020,2030,2040,2050},
    ytick={6,8,10,15,...,30},
    ]

    %\addplot {8*1.08^x};
    %\addlegendentry{8\%}

    \addplot[   color=black,
                solid,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid},
                smooth] coordinates {
        (2005,6)
        (2006,7.32)
        (2007,9.42)
        (2008,10.29)
        (2009,8.09)
        (2010,6.73)
        (2011,9.60)
        (2012,9.62)
        (2013,8.66)
        (2014,8)

    };
    \addlegendentry{Retail}




\addplot+[mark=none,draw=none,fill=orange!70,domain=2014:2050] {8*1.07^(x-2014)}\closedcycle;

\addplot+[mark=none,draw=none,fill=white,domain=2014:2050] {8*1.03^(x-2014)}\closedcycle;




\addplot[name path global=T,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.75:2050,label={[below]{3\%}}]{8.*(1.03)^( x -  2014 )};
    %\addlegendentry{3\% inflation}

    \addplot[label={[below]{5\%}},name path global = F,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.85:2048,]{8.*(1.05)^( x -  2014 )};
    %\addlegendentry{5\% inflation}


    \addplot[label={[below]{7\%}},name path global=S,color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,domain=2013.85:2050]{8.*(1.07)^( x -  2014 )};


\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed to the `standalone` class just for the example to avoid an overfull box (your image is too wide for standard margins).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use fill between, but the solution is fragile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{ wasysym }
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}% note addition
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style={%
   postaction={ decorate,transform shape,
   decoration={ markings, mark=at position .2 with \node #1;}}}]

    \begin{axis}[
      width=\textwidth,
      legend cell align=left,
      legend pos=outer north east,
      legend style={draw=none},
      %height=9cm,
      xlabel=Year,
      ylabel=\$/kWh,
      xmin=2004,   xmax=2050,
      ymin=5,   ymax=35,
      %xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      %width=9cm,
      xtick={2005,  2010, 2013, 2020, 2030, 2040,2050},
      xticklabels={05,10,13,2020,2030,2040,2050},
      ytick={6,8,10,15,...,30},
    ]

    %\addplot {8*1.08^x};
    %\addlegendentry{8\%}

    \addplot[   color=black,
                solid,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid},
                smooth] coordinates {
        (2005,6)
        (2006,7.32)
        (2007,9.42)
        (2008,10.29)
        (2009,8.09)
        (2010,6.73)
        (2011,9.60)
        (2012,9.62)
        (2013,8.66)
        (2014,8)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Retail}

\addplot[name path=S,draw=none,mark=none,domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.07)^( x -  2014 )};
%\addplot[name path=F,draw=none,mark=none,domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.05)^( x -  2014 )};
\addplot[name path=T,draw=none,mark=none,domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.03)^( x -  2014 )};
\addplot[orange] fill between[of=S and T];

\addplot[color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,label={[below]{7\%}},domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.07)^( x -  2014 )};
\addplot[color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,label={[below]{5\%}},domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.05)^( x -  2014 )};
\addplot[color=black,line width=0.75,dashed,label={[below]{3\%}},domain=2013.85:2050] {8.*(1.03)^( x -  2014 )};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: note labels]